# Flask Admin - dependent dropdown

Tags: python, flask-admin

I am trying to create a dependent dropdown in a specific Form in Flask Admin.

I'd like to choose a value from a dropdown 1 and automatically fill a dropdown 2.

I got the dropdown 2 updating by form_args, but I cannot find out how to get the value from dropdown 1.

```
class ContaView(ModelView):


form_args = {
    'sub_categoria_nome': {
        'query_factory': lambda: categoria.SubCategoria.query.filter_by(
            categoria_id=1
        )
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7iu6.png)